# Preemtive Multitasking in Userspace

Tags: assembly, x86-64, multitasking, green-threads

I'm trying to implement green threads/processes in assembly.

For example, I got this x64 assembly code (nasm syntax) with two loops. It outputs a lot of 'a's, but I want it to output 'a's and 'b's. This is of course not a real example, as just combining the two loops would solve the problem.

```
global main

extern printf

section .text
main:

 .t1:
    mov eax, 0
    mov rdi, a
    call printf
    jmp .t1

 .t2:
    mov eax, 0
    mov rdi, b
    call printf
    jmp .t2

section .data
  a: db "a", 0
  b: db "b", 0
```

So I'd like to write some kind of scheduler which changes the instruction pointer to `main.t1` or `main.t2` every few microseconds while saving some registers and changing the stack pointer.

I understand if this is impossible in userspace, it seems quite unlikely a process can change a running program as this would introduce some security vulnarities. If it can't be done from userspace, would it be possible with a kernel module?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it is possible in kernel mode. Use interrupts from timer. I cannot figure out how much you know from your question, so sorry if speaking on obvious things. Begin with real-mode 16-bit code, it's much simpler. Write a .COM DOS program with both scheduler and threads (if you want, you can write the loader later). Set the timer interrupt vector at your scheduler/dispatcher routine. Writing dispatcher (the state save/load routine) is straightforward: the interrupt will save CS:IP, it's your task to save other registers, the same with loading. The scheduler is a bit more tricky, probably the simplest scheduler is "round-robin", which simply alternates between threads, giving each an equal time piece. You may implement it using ring linked list.
Also, in some operating systems (*nix, afaik) it is possible to do the same thing using signals.